# Powershell copy file with variable

Tags: variables, powershell

I'm trying to run the following script that I thought was quite simple. What am I doing wring here...

```
[Environment]::UserName = $username

Write-Host "The user is $username"
$from = "c:\Users\" + $username + "\favourites\*.*" 
$to = "c:\test"

Write-Host "This is from dir: $from"
Write-Host "This is to dir: $to"

Copy-Item $from $to
```

The script does not seem to like the `+ $username +` ...

Answer (score 8):

I think you got your first line the wrong way around. Currently you're assigning an empty variable (value of it should be `$null`) to `$Env:UserName`, thus overwriting the username, not reading it.

I think it should be

```
$username = [Environment]::Username
```

or, as noted above, you can access environment variables via the special `Env:` drive:

```
$username = $Env:Username
```

---

And unrelated to your problem, just a matter of nicer code:

1. You can put the username directly into the string (which you seem to know, as demonstrated a line above – where you don't need a string in this case, though):

   ```
   $from = "C:\Users\$username\favourites\*"
   ```
2. You don't need to fetch the user name at all, you can use

   ```
   $Env:UserProfile
   ```

   or

   ```
   [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::UserProfile)
   ```

   or even

   ```
   [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Favorites)
   ```

   which might ultimately be what you're after, here.